# Is there an automatic way for a secondary member to promote to primary member in a replica set?

Tags: replication, mongodb, mongodb-4.2

Here is my setup:

```
Node 1 = 10.1.0.1 (Primary) - priority 1
Node 2 = 10.1.0.2 (Secondary) - priority 1
Node 3 = 10.1.0.3 (Secondary) - priority 0
```

In the event of Node 1 failure, Node 2 will be set to Primary of the mongo replica set.

Once Node 1 is already accessible, is there a way to automatically promote it to Primary and Node 2 will be set to Secondary again once Node 1 catches up on the replica set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easily! Set priority of node 1 to higher than 1...

```
Node 1 = 10.1.0.1 (Primary) - priority 2
Node 2 = 10.1.0.2 (Secondary) - priority 1
Node 3 = 10.1.0.3 (Secondary) - priority 0.5
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why Node 1 will be set to priority = 2. Isnt it that the lower the priority, the more it is being prioritized in election of primary?

Comment: I think my understanding is the opposite. My bad :D

Comment: Think it like this.. With priority 2, node1 gets two times more votes than node2. :-)

Comment: In essence, the mongo replica set do not need something to trigger the election of primary is that right? As long as there are members that have higher priority, it will always switch back to them?

Comment: That something (what triggers election this time) is even when node1 changes its status from RECOVERY2 to SECONDARY. That point Node1 get all votes and node2 will change it status to SECONDARY. Then node1 says, well boys and girls... It looks like that I'm voted as the PRIMARY... ;-) So every time than one of the nodes change it status, election is done.  BTW, don't forget to "mark" right answer as a "right answer"

Comment: Thanks JJussi. so basically once the previous primary (with higher priority) is up again, its status will be set to recovery2 since it will first sync the data that is missing and once done, it changes its status to secondary that will trigger an election of primary depending on the member's priority :)

Answer (score 1):

The main factor here is the [Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/replica-set-elections/).

***Replica sets use elections to determine which set member will become primary***. Replica sets can trigger an election in response to a variety of events, such as:

- Adding a new node to the replica set,
- Initiating a replica set,
- Performing replica set maintenance using methods such as
  `rs.stepDown()` or `rs.reconfig()`, and
- The secondary members losing connectivity to the primary for more
  than the configured timeout (10 seconds by default).

I think this is what you are looking for:

[rs.stepDown()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/rs.stepDown/)
instructs the primary of the replica set to become a secondary. After the primary steps down, eligible secondaries will hold an election for a new primary.

Another option would be that you can force a replica set member to become primary by giving it a higher `members[n].priority` value than any other member in the set. Note that a majority of the configured members of a replica set must be available for a replica set to reconfigure or elect a primary.